# How can I pass C++ Lists and Vectors as parameters to a C# COM visible method?

Tags: c#, c++

I have created a COM Visible C# class (along with its interfaces) and I need it to process some data that comes from C++ where I have variables of type:

```
std::vector<int> intV;
```

and

```
std::list<std::vector<std::list<double>>> pointV;
```

I need to pass them as arguments to the C# class but I don't know what should be my method signature on the C# side.

Comment: You can't.  You can however pass a pointer to the data.

Comment: C++ collection classes have interop capabilities that compare unfavorably to a stone brick.  They can't even interop with another C++ compiler.  Or the same compiler with different build options. Think C or pointers or a chatty interface that exchanges simple types one at a time.

Comment: @EdS. yes, but a pointer to a `std::list<std::vector<std::list<double>>>` will be USELESS. One weird way would be to make an C++-CLI Iterator wrapper

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: I never said a pointer to an STL type.  You would pass a pointer to the *data*, i.e., `get()` or `&v[0]` for a `vector`.  `list` is a different beast entirely.  C++ has no standard ABI, you have to pass around simple (POD) types (or COM types).

Comment: I meant `data()`, not `get()`

Comment: Thanks for saving me some restless nights. I ended up converting them to bi-dimensional arrays since the list<double> had a "fixed" length.